# ASP.net website on publish the register tool creates new db

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure, asp.net-authentication

I made an ASP.net application and now I want to publish the application to an azure server.
Everything works fine but when I want to register a user with the build in authentication he want's to create a new database. But I want it in the same database of the database with all the data from the application.

My connection string DefaultConnection is correct. And my IdentityModel is set correct I think.

```
 public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }
}
```

When I run the application local it all works.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to create an Azure Sql Database and point your app to that database

Comment: I did that, it's not Local but on the same SQL server. I get my data from all the tables but the authentication doesn't work